# SSRS 2005 report in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Afternoon All,

I have a couple of bar graphs that use a dataset each with a specified stored procedure that it uses to collect the data from my SQL database.

The data that it is pulling back is live data that i have set to refresh every 30 seconds.

I have managed to do this by setting the autorefresh on the report to 30 seconds.  However im wondering if there is a better way to have the report refresh as the refresh is slow and load the images when and for a brief moment the bar graphs dissaper while this is loading?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Betty

Answer (score 0):

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/report-caching-in-sql-server-reporting-services-2008-r2.html

It might help you to save some data in cache to make it little fast

This is to make some sub report to fetch data fast

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2314/ssrs-report-parts-versus-sub-reports-faq/